# Wordpress website suddenly receiving a 403 when trying to load critical files (CSS/JS)

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403, css

Out of the blue my Wordpress website has stopped loading properly. I've checked the console and it is full of lines similar to this:

```
GET https://teachifyapp.com/wp-content/cache/wpfc-minified/jr2pizz7/63j5f.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403
```

Can somebody give me direction? It seems like a permissions issue and I would love to know how I could fix it. Do I need to check the .htaccess file? And if so, what am I looking for? It currently has very little code in it. (PHP 7 update, Litespeed noabort, and https rewrite).

If anybody can provide assistance, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be folder permissions.

Check your permissions using Filezilla or some other FTP program.

You can also use a security plugin like iThemes Security to review your permissions.

```
These should be the Default Permissions
644 -rw-r--r--  /wp-config.php
644 -rw-r--r--  /.htaccess


These are more Secured Permissions
600 -rw-------  /wp-config.php
604 -rw----r--  /.htaccess
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me feedback, I appreciate you taking the time mate.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the issue resolved.

There was an update to a security feature called Imunify360 on the server side. For reference there is more information here:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/autoptimize-not-able-to-contact-server-403-error/#post-12076940